# Real time max aggregation from DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Problem context -

I have 2 DynamoDB named Shop and Product.

Shop attributes -

```
Shop_id (partition key)
Shop_Name
```

Product attributes-

```
Product_id(partition key)
Product_Name
Shop_Id
Price
```

Problem -
Create a new field `max_price` in Shop dynamoDB and that should be updated when price of products are updated.
The main problem is when price is decreased how to find the next max price.
Also i cannot create a GSI in Product DynamoDB. (New index cannot be added in DB, adding new attributes are only allowed)

What approaches I thought of -
Using max heap and min heap is one way to maintain/obtain max_price but implementing heaps will require 2 more dynamoDB

Is there a simpler approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely cannot create an index on the Product table, then the next best option I can think of is to create a new DynamoDB table that has `Shop_Id` as a hash key and `Price` as a sort key and set up near real-time replication between Product table and this new table using DynamoDB Streams and Lambda. You can then use new table to easily get the max price using sort key. You could also use something like sorted sets in ElastiCache redis instead of a DynamoDB table.

Comment: I read that ElasticCache Redis is sorted based on rank. In my use case i need to have product to be sorted on price which can be achieved by rank but the main problem is that the partition key should be shop_id else i wont be able to get max product price under a particular shop.

Comment: Apart from using a DynamoDB with sort key is there any other alternative ? I do not want to go with this because sorting should also be based on types of products.

Comment: @wolf - Sorted sets allow you to specify score per item, so it's up to you how to calculate that score. You can have a set per shop_id, so that you can get ordering within each shop independently. Also not sure what the concern with DynamoDB is, since you can have multiple sort keys or even create a composite field like <productId:price> if you need to be able to sort by productId/price combination.

Comment: Yes DynamoDB seems to be the correct option. I just have 1 more doubt, if i keep shop_id as partition key and product_id_price as sort key how will i update the dynamoDB when the price of product is updated ?

Comment: @wolf - Good question. Your dynamoDB stream should contain both old and new value, so when you process the stream you can use the old value to find the key of the record that needs to be updated.

Comment: Also how will the composite sort key created ? if i create sort key like = product_id_bid then the sorting on product price wont be achieved  and i wont be able to get the correct max price under a shop.

Comment: @wolf - Apologies, you're right the product_id_bid combo won't work as they're different types. I think what can work is having two indexes in the new table: first index will use shop_id as a hash key and bid as a sort key. This index will help you find max price per shop. The second index will use shop_id:product_id combo as hash key and bid as a sort key, and will allow you to find max price per product in a shop

Comment: This approach also has an issue because sort key needs to be unique but in my case 2 products can have same price and in that case sort key will no longer be unique.

Comment: They don’t have to be unique in an index. Only in the primary table. Your primary table should use some unique ID

Comment: Do you mean to say i should use GSI ?

Comment: Yes. Basically this entire solution is a workaround for not being able to create GSI in your original table, so the workaround is to create a new table, sync data from the original into the new table and create GSIs there.